# How to make POST request on Google Firebase Firestore using pure JavaScript anbd Fetch API

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fetch-api

Currently, I can easily make a GET request in Firestore, the document-oriented database of Google Firebase, but the POST has been difficult. I need to do it using pure JavaScript and using the Fetch API as per REST API standards, since I will be using the code in a low-code tool called AppGyver, which allows integration with Vanilla JS.

GET request I make and it works:

```
var project_id = [valor]
var api_key = [valor]
var collection = [valor]

var url_table = `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${project_id}/databases/(default)/documents/${collection}?key=${api_key}`
var response = await fetch(url_table);
var json = await response.json();
```

Below is an example of how I usually make this type of request in Airtable, another tool similar to a database, but I don't know how to adapt it to Firestore.

```
var options = 
{
    method: REQUEST_TYPE,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json", 
        "Authorization": API_AUTHORIZATION
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(
        {
            "fields": 
            {
                "NOME": RECORD['nome'],
                "TIPO": RECORD['tipo'],
                "STATUS": "ATIVO"
            }
        }
    )
}
```

In this case, I pass this options variable inside the response, getting:

`var response = await fetch(url_table, options)`

Obs: Sorry any English error, I used Google Translate.

Comment: "*but I don't know how to adapt it to Firestore*" - did you try anything?  If so, what was that?  Please edit the question to show the code you have that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson This:

```var project_id = [value]
var api_key = [value]
var collection = [value]
var url = 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1';

var options = {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({fields: { nome: { stringValue: 'newTitle' } } }),
}

let url_table = `${url}/${project_id}/databases/(default)/documents/${collection}?documentId=1235345354&key=[value]`
let response = await fetch(url_table, options);
let json = await response.json();```

Comment: Please add all relevant information into the question itself by editing it.  Do not leave important info in comments, especially not code, as it's hard to read.